# How to program a button made in code

Tags: vb.net

For example, if on form load Button1 was created, how would I make this button function?

Comment: When you double click it in the gui you create an event handler. There you can write the code to do what you need

Comment: winforms? webforms? wpf? be specific.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public WithEvents newButton As Windows.Forms.Button

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 5
        newButton = New Windows.Forms.Button
        newButton.Name = "btnButton" & i
        newButton.Text = "Button " & i
        newButton.Top = 20 + i * 30
        newButton.Left = 40

        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClicked
        Me.Controls.Add(newButton)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("You clicked: " & sender.name &amp;amp; vbCrLf & "Button name: " & sender.Text)
End Sub
```

[Reference](http://brian-dao.blogspot.com/2007/06/programmatically-add-event-handlers-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you double click the button in the designer view you will be taken to the code-behind for the `Button_Click` event.  There you can add any functionality you want to have happen when the button is clicked by the user.

Comment: You cannot click the button in the designer. It is created on form load.